# In Whitehead and Russell's PM, are homogenous relations the only ones that have relation numbers?

Tags: logic, math-history, foundations

Given the definition of ordinal similarity:

✳151.01 $P \overline{smor} Q = \hat{S}\{ S\in 1\rightarrow 1. C‘Q=ConverseD‘S. P=S^;Q\}$  Df.

$Q$ has to be homogeneous, otherwise $C‘Q$ is meaningless. It does not seem to imply that $P$ has to be homogeneous. If  $P$ is heterogeneous, $smor$ would be asymmetrical, because $C‘P$ would be meaningless.

✳151.14 says $smor$ is symmetrical. In this case, I think it is presumed that $P$ is homogeneous.

Take $\iota$ for example, given an individual, say Indv, as its first term, then it forms a progression-like relation P:

> Indv, {Indv}, {{Indv}}, {{{indv}}}, ...

$P$ does not have a field or a domain because $\iota$ is heterogeneous. If there is a correlator $S$ that converts P's relata to string, then $S^;P$ will be a homogeneous progression in which each term wraps a layer of $\{\}$ around the one immediately precedes itself.  The cardinal number of $S^;P$'s field is $\aleph_0$.

If ordinal similarity is limited to homogeneous relations only, then the above procedure is inoperable.

Please let me know what is wrong with my reasoning.

Thanks,

Comment: Your example with Indv is not clear to me ... I think that the issue with *smor* is like the issue with *sm*; *cardinal numbers* are (roughly speaking) classes of classes. Thus, if we do not impose the condition of *homegeneity*, the "similar" classes are not of the same type; thus, their "collection" into a class forming its cardinal number it is not allowed.

Comment: I agree. Before we start to count something, that something has to be a legitimate collection, i.e. a class whose members are of the same type. I was trying to count the number of types. Types can never be grouped into one class, thus it is meaningless to say the cardinal number of types. But relation doesn't have this restriction. One relation can connect different types. $\iota$ connects $x$ to {x}, {x} to {{x}}, etc. If I can count the relation number of $\iota$ than I can say types have an ordinal number.

Comment: But before I get started, I realized that ordinal similarity is defined between homogeneous relations, i.e. each relation's field must consist of members of the same type.

Comment: Intuitively yes ... but I think that you are on the "edge" of the paradoxes. [Burali-Forti paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burali-Forti_paradox) regards the set of all ordinal numbers. Thus, I think that in *PM* we cannot have the ordinal number of the "collection" of types... we cannot have a class of all types either...

Comment: I understand similarity can happen between different types of relations, but each relation's field must be of the same type.